# Finding Outlook contacts whose notes contain attachment

Tags: c#, outlook

I've exported a outlook contacts folder to a csv file.  One thing I've noticed is that the notes field has attachments for some contacts.  There seems to be no indication of this in the csv file.  Is there a way to find contacts whose notes contain an attachment?
I'd like to use C# if I can't use Outlook directly.

Comment: I have loaded a pst into Outlook and that is what I'm trying to access.  It comes up as Outlook data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, create a query on the `PR_HASATTACH` MAPI property - something like

```
attachmentItems = MyFolder.Items.Restrict("@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B\" = true"
```